# How to select some default nodes in Google Org Chart

Tags: orgchart

I am new to Google Org Chart.

Having a tough time selecting some default nodes in my chart by code.

[image: Org Chart]

Like in this case I want "jordan" to be selected automatically.

Note: Node selection is dynamic

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last done by myself.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data.addColumn('string', 'Group');
data.addColumn('string', 'Parent');
data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

var response = [
                ['Mark', '', 'Mark'],
                ['John', 'Mark', 'John'],
                ['Mary', 'Mark', 'Mary'],
                ['Jordan', 'Mary', 'Jordan'],
                ['Eli', 'Mary', 'Eli'],
                ['Ivan', 'Mary', 'Ivan'],
                ['Sarah', 'John', 'Sarah'],
                ['Mike', 'John', 'Mike']
              ];
data.addRows(response);

var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('grouporgdiv'));
chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});

var selectedArray = new Array();
var counter = 0;
var commaSeperatedDefaultValues = "Jordan";
var defaultValuesArray = commaSeperatedDefaultValues.split(",");

for(i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
    chart.setSelection([{row: i}]);
    var temp = chart.getSelection()[0];
    var a = defaultValuesArray.indexOf(data.getValue(temp.row, 2));
    if(a != -1)
        selectedArray[counter++] = temp;
}

chart.setSelection(selectedArray);
```